# C# query about gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I am using Visual Studio 2008, language C# and MS Access as backend. There is one form with GridView control, when I click on the text box event, the gridview shows the data, but at the run time, when I want to add another record on the gridview it will replace the first entry in gridview. I want it below the first entry with auto increment of gridview???

Comment: nothing is auto, you need to modify your previous datasource (add new record) then bind to gridview again. For sorting, you have to add something like row number/id/etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mr. Marco Bong sir...but where to add row number or id??? In the database or in coding part??

Comment: it's additional column for sorting etc, you can do in either in database / c# part

Comment: Did your grid-view bound with database data or only to the textbox value?you could use ViewState to save your previously bound data and add rows to that then bind grid-view again.For autoincrement you could use `Container.DataItemIndex +1 `

Comment: Yes, it is bound with database data. can you please explain use of ViewState??

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
 if (Session["data"] == null) 
     {            
        dt.Columns.Add("ID");
        dt.Columns.Add("Fist_Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("last_Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("Address");
        DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
        dr1[0] = TextBox1.Text;
        dr1[1] = TextBox2.Text;
        dr1[2] = TextBox3.Text;
        dr1[3] = TextBox4.Text;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr1);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        Session["Data"] = dt;

    } 
else
 {
        dt = (DataTable)Session["Data"];
        DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
        dr1[0] = TextBox1.Text;
        dr1[1] = TextBox2.Text;
        dr1[2] = TextBox3.Text;
        dr1[3] = TextBox4.Text;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr1);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        Session.Remove("Data");
        Session["Data"] = dt;
    }
```

and add top

```
 using system.data;

    datatable dt=new datatable();

it will work
```